# Keyboard shortcuts in Firefox don't work as expected

Tags: firefox, shortcut-keys, mate

Previously, on Ubuntu and other systems, the following shortcuts in Firefox would work:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> - Switches between tabs
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> - Closes current tab

Since installing the Mate desktop (Gnome 2), the shortcuts do the following:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> - Does nothing
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> - Closes Firefox

I've checked in the "Keyboard Shortcuts" section in Mate, but neither of these are being overridden. Compiz isn't installed.

This is rather annoying.

Comment: please add your answer in the answers section below, not in the question section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [originally posted](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/140124/2)

> The Firefox extension "FoxTab 1.4.5" was responsible for breaking these shortcuts. Disabling it restores the desired functionality.